# Why does not <div style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}></div> render black but <div style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}> Hello </div> doesn't?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to learn React.JS and something kind of blew my mind.

I have this Header component :

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }} />;
  }
}
```

that I am calling in my App.js :

```
function App() {
  return <Header />;
}
```

When the code stays like this, nothing shows on my web page. But if I change my Header component to this :

```
class Header extends Component {
      render() {
        return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}> Hi</div>;
      }
    }
```

I get a black line on the top of my web page.

I don't understand why writing something into my div makes me get the blackline, and I was wondering how can I get the black background without writing anything in my  ?

Comment: Try changing the style to style={{ backgroundColor: "black", height: "32px" }}
It looks like there is no height to your element, so once you add the text it fills your component. The reason you're seeing a black bar is because the text color for the div is also black. To see the text also add color:"white" to the style.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? unless you specifically tell it to, a div doesn't grow in height bigger than it's content.  You weren't seeing anything in the first example because the div has no content, therefore it's height is 0.  You were seeing a black line in the second example because the word "Hi" was added, which made the div grow to be big enough to show the word "Hi".

Comment: To add to this, @phishfordead, the text is not visible because it is black on black.

Comment: @StianPoisson No problem, please review the React styling guide by W3Schools for more information https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

Comment: @KaydenvanRijn I wasn't at all explaining why the text wasn't visible.  I was explaining why the OP was seeing a black line when he added the word "Hi" to his div.  Just because the text seems "invisible" since it is black on black doesn't mean that the div won't grow to accommodate the text.

Comment: @phishfordead Yes and I was adding to your comment to add clarity.

Comment: @KaydenvanRijn, my bad, I didn't read the "To add to this" portion of that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header doesn't have a height so in the case that it has no text it is a height of 0px so you don't see the background color, if you add text to the header it stretches to accommodate the text so it gets a height automatically and that is why you see the back background.

If you want to have an empty header with a black background try editing your code as mentioned by @Kayden van Rijn like this `style={{ backgroundColor: "black", height: "32px" }}`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of reasons for this:

1. `div` is not a self-closing tag, i.e. you can't use it like `<div />` and instead it must be used as `<div></div>`
2. An empty `div` has no height so there is nothing to add background colour to.

To fix this you must

1. Add a style to the div which specifies the height e.g. `height: "32px"`
2. To see the text, you must change the color of the text so it is visible e.g. `color: "white", backgroundColor: "black"`

```
return <div style={{ height: "32px", color: "white", backgroundColor: "black" }}> Hi</div>;
```